# Conversion coming from Youtube ads

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to find a way to track "paid traffic" from Youtube, ie. people who click on one of our ads, got redirected to one of our videos, then clicked on a link in the comment section. At the moment everybody coming from Youtube appears under the Youtube channel in our analytics.

Yet, inside Youtube Analytics, I can see that 90% of people watching specific videos come from paid traffic.

I tried to see if I could get any possible information from the youtube APIs but it looks like nothing is useful, event to determine how could be the split between paid/unpaid traffic.

Also, impossible to find a split by video.. except in GA. Therefore, no possible link?!

1/ Is it possible to link paid traffic internal to Youtube and part of the "youtube" channel traffic in GA? data-wise or just mathematically?
2/ Is there a way to hadve an idea or approximate the convertion rate?

PS: I know this should not be seen a pure conversion channel*

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

**1. Is it possible to link paid traffic internal to YouTube and part of the "YouTube" channel traffic in Google Analytics? data-wise or just mathematically?**

- As far as I know, yes it is possible. In fact, there's no better way to analyze your new brand channel layout than integrating it with Google Analytics. Reasons as given:

  > The main difference between YouTube analytics and Google Analytics is that the former provides data about the videos, while the latter provide data about the visitors of the channel’s pages.

  To use this feature, please refer to the steps given in [How to integrate your YouTube One brand channel with Google Analytics](http://www.amazeemetrics.com/en/blog/how-integrate-your-youtube-one-brand-channel-google-analytics)

**2. Is there a way to have an idea or approximate the conversion rate?**

- I tried looking for documentation on conversion rate but it seems that this doesn't exist as also mentioned in [Conversion rate between YouTube views and track sales](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141012063820-59599640-typical-conversion-rate-between-youtube-views-and-track-sales)
- And, as suggested in [Google AdWords Help](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2456138?hl=en), in tracking viewer conversions for video ads,

  > Since video advertising doesn’t always drive immediate conversions, we recommend that you look at view-through conversion data, which shows the number of online conversions that happened within 30 days after a viewer saw, but did not click, your video ad.

I hope that helps.